# abstract syntax tree of Lua function

Tags: lua, abstract-syntax-tree

I am new to Lua and I was reading about the AST (abstract syntax tree) but didn't quite get it yet.

I wrote a simple "Hello-World" function in Lua:

```
function foo()
    value = 10
    num = "to the"
    if value > 2 then
       print("Hello World")
    end
return value
end
print(foo())
```

Simple program which it's output is:

```
Hello World
10
```

I want to build an abstract syntax tree but not sure where and how to start.

I read about the syntax [here](http://www.example.com/), alought didn't figure out how to "design"/"draw" the wanted tree.

Answer (score 3):

I'd start by studying the output of existing modules that build ASTs, as it will make it more clear what the elements of the tree are and how they correspond to the code you write. You can start with [Metalua](https://github.com/fab13n/metalua).